# Crontab php fail

Tags: php

My cron file says:
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php

And cron.php is executable and located at /var/www/html/cron.php, still it doesn't work at all. My cron.php file:

```
<?php
include('Includes/top.php');

$Cron->closeServer();
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have "root" there? It should not be necessary to specify the username, this will attempt to execute the command `root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php`

Comment: @rickdenhaan it doesn't work without either

Comment: We need more info here. On the face of it - `$Cron` isn't clearly defined.

Comment: @HPierce it works when I just visit that file in the browser, so that isn't the problem

Comment: i guess problem will be in php location `/usr/bin/php`, open terminal and run the command `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php` do you see any error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `include()` is relative and you're probably not in the right working dir.

Change your command to `cd /var/www/html && /usr/bin/php cron.php`